# java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: java, ms-access

When I run this code to connect to ms access db i get this error:"Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

```
public static Connection getConnection() {
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver    (*.mdb,*.accdb)};DBQ=D:/FontsDB.accdb;";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return conn;
}
```

---

I use Netbean7.4,JDK1.7,MS office2013,Win7_64 bit,
I changed odbc properties from `%windir%\system32\odbcad32.exe`to`%windir%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` and also i get this error.

Answer (score 0):

The Driver specification

```
Driver={Microsoft Access Driver    (*.mdb,*.accdb)}
```

is not valid. You need to use

```
Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}
```

Spacing is important.

Comment: This is from the site not from me and it is unbelievable to leave this space!

Comment: @user3649116 Did you not copy and paste your code directly into your question? In any event, double-check the spacing in the connection string that your Java code is using.

Answer (score 0):

this problem can be solve using **install jdk 7** to download go 
to below link

> http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html
>
> Java SE Development Kit 7u79

Product / File Description : Windows x86
Size: 138.31 MB
Download: jdk-7u79-windows-i586.exe

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes